# Link to .cshtml view from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can you point directly to a .cshtml view from javascript file? 
For example why can't I use a .cshtml view with angular.js? 
like in this example:

```
 .directive('encoder', ($timeout) => {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: 'isolate',
            locals: { service: 'bind' },
            templateUrl: 'encoderTemplate.cshtml' // <-- that's not possible?
        }
    });
```

It's of course possible to have an action method that returns whatever you want, but I'm curious if it's possible to reference directly to the razor view.

Comment: No, because IIS won't serve the .cshtml file, since it doesn't recognize it as a static file.  You might consider setting up a dummy controller that serves to pass through a specified .cshtml file directly.

Comment: will you please make it an answer... thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, you can't serve up .cshtml files directly, However, you can use a controller to render the content if you so choose:

```
public class TemplateController : Controller
{
    // create a ~/Views/Template/Encoder.cshtml file
    public PartialViewResult Encoder()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Then reference it like you would with `@Url.Action`:

```
{
    ....
    templateUrl: '@Url.Action("Encoder", "Template")'
}
```

---

*From Comment*

If you have most of the JavaScript code outside of something that has Razor access (e.g. external .js file) you can still take advantage of the Url builder, just have to do so a little differently. For instance, I may do something like:

```
public class TemplateController : Controller
{
    // Add a child method to the templates controller that outputs default
    // configuration settings (and, since it's a child action, we can re-use it)
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult Index()
    {
        // You could build a dynamic IEnumerable<ConfigRef> model
        // here and pass it off, but I'm just going to stick with a static view
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**~/Views/Template/Index.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (typeof window.App === 'undefined'){
    window.App = {};
  }
  App.Templates = {
    Encoder: '@Url.Action("Encoder", "Template")',
    Template1: '@Url.Action("Template1", "Template")',
    Template2: '@Url.Action("Template2", "Template")'
  };
</script>
@*
   the template files would then reference `App.Templates.Encoder`
   when they need access to that template.
*@
@Scripts.Render("~/js/templating")
```

**Index.cshtml** (or whatever is any view)

```
@* ... *@
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "Template"); }
@* ... *@
```

Comment: I won't be able to use @Url.Action because the code comes from javascript that sits in separate .js file and is not embedded to a razor view

Comment: @Agzam: You can also store global setting in the site root which are then references in child files. `var SiteSettings = { templates: { encoder: '@Url.Action("Encoder","Template)' } }` then `templateUrl: SiteSettings.templates.encoder`

Answer (score 6):

Another option is:

1.Add TemplatesController with EncoderTemplate view

```
public class TemplatesController : Controller
{

     public ActionResult EncoderTemplate()
     {

           return View();
     }

}
```

2.Add Layout = null to EncoderTemplate.schtml view

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>Your html goes here</div>
```

3.Point to the EncoderTemplate.schtml as shown below

```
.directive('encoder', ($timeout) => {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: 'isolate',
        locals: { service: 'bind' },
        templateUrl: '/Templates/EncoderTemplate' // you should not add .schtml
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done and it works a charm. However to date I have not worked out how to unit test this with Jasmine in Visual Studio using Resharper as the runner. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I am not using Resharper.