# How to create modal in mvc(cshtml)?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have controller in angular :

```
 $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({

            templateUrl: 'Sport/Offer',

        });
    }
```

MVC Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Offer()
  {
       return PartialView("Offer", new OfferModel());
  }
```

Problem is when i click on button it open modal but with same page that im already on it. Any suggestion why is this happening and how to fix that ?Is it because of wrong url or what? Do i need some controller that will handle that?

Comment: why your  tempalte is without html extension? And what controller do you pass? Or it's just for simplicity?

Comment: @Artiom im using .cshtml thats why i dont have .html

Comment: how are you going to use cshtml with angular? angular doesn't have to know anything about cshtml or other asp.net specific things. Create an html file with angular view template and here you go.

Comment: im using cshtml with angular all the time

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a controller `Sport` and action `Offer` for this view?

> .cshtml file contains server side code, to render it you need to use a controller and action. They will render that .cshtml file for you. So have a controller action return that view for you and use the url to the controller action in your angular route.

[Link to .cshtml view from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631447/link-to-cshtml-view-from-javascript)

Comment: I have controller and action but problem is what ever i put in templateUrl it open me page that im already on

Comment: @uzhas how do you call this method? May be you just refreshing your current page without even executing you code? please provide your view where you starting executing your code.

Comment: @uzhas if you comment modal.open code, does it stop to refresh?